# Can a descriptor be assigned to an instance attribute instead of a class attribute?

Tags: python, descriptor

I am looking into Python descriptors. So far, all of the examples I have found on Google assign a descriptor object only class attributes.

Should a descriptor be always be assigned to a class attribute? Can a descriptor be assigned to an instance attribute? If so, any examples or use cases?

For example, all examples are like:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):  
    x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')  
    y = 5
```

Can we have something like:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):  
    init(self ):  
        x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')  
        y = 5
```

Comment: What do you mean? A class is an object. You can read about the full protocol here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: The following is from the example from the link you pasted  
 >>> class MyClass(object):  
     x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')  
     y = 5    
Can we have something like  
 >>> class MyClass(object):  
  init(self ):  
      x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')  
      y = 5

Comment: We'll have you tried that? What happened?