# Is there a way to assign a descriptor to an instance attribute at runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-descriptors

*This question was asked in 2016, but was not answered: [Can a descriptor be assigned to an instance attribute instead of a class attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36008235/2954547)*

I have a basic descriptor

```py
class MyThing:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        print(f'Assigned to {name} on {owner}')
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, typ):
        print(f'Getting {self.name} on {obj}')
        return getattr(obj, self.name)

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print(f'Setting {self.name} on {obj} to {val}')
        setattr(obj, self.name, val)
```

Is it possible to assign an instance of this descriptor to some other class instance at runtime, and have it behave in accordance with the descriptor protocol?

The naive approach fails:

```py
foo.thing = MyThing()
```

`foo.thing` does not behave like a descriptor, it just behaves like a typical instance attribute.

This is not an XY problem. I am specifically asking for an answer to the question as I have stated it.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for "mixins"? Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20022860/4799172). I'm much less-sure about "at runtime" though, on that suggestion

Comment: @roganjosh I am specifically asking if this is possible to achieve at runtime, as I described in the question. If the answer is "no", then the answer is "no".

Comment: Of course *you can* assign a descriptor to an instance attirbute, but *that won't be considered by the descriptor protocol*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the descriptor protocol only works when the descriptor object is *a member of a class*, this is stated int [the HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#primer):

> To use the descriptor, it must be stored as a class variable in
> another class

Or, from the [data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors):

> The following methods only apply when an instance of the class
> containing the method (a so-called descriptor class) appears in an
> owner class (the descriptor must be in either the owner’s class
> dictionary or in the class dictionary for one of its parents).